# How can I use ng-switch to toggle displaying a nested table with AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to use ng-switch in AngularJS to expand a row in a table list to show another table (containing more details about that list item) when it's clicked.

However, I'm having trouble displaying the nested table. I've noticed that the problem only happens with nested tables. If I'm using ng-switch to expand a td instead of a table, it works as expected.

Here's a JSFiddle and my code to illustrate the problem: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b5qdah7t/)

The html:

```
<body ng-app="listAndDetails">
<div>
    <table class="table table-bordered" ng-controller="ListAndOneDetailCtrl">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>e-mail</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody ng-repeat="user in users" ng-click="toggleSelected()" ng-switch on="isSelected(user)">
        <tr>
            <td>{{user.name}}</td>
            <td>{{user.email}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-switch-when="true" class="light-gray">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Country</td>
                    <td>Address</td>
                    <td>Description</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>{{user.country}}</td>
                    <td>{{user.address}}</td>
                    <td>{{user.desc}}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<div ng-controller="ListAndManyDetailsCtrl">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>e-mail</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody ng-repeat="user in users" ng-controller="UserCtrl" ng-click="toggleSelected()" ng-switch on="isSelected()">
        <tr>
            <td>{{user.name}}</td>
            <td>{{user.email}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-switch-when="true" class="light-gray">
            <td>{{user.country}}</td>
            <td>{{user.address}}</td>
            <td>{{user.desc}}</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
```

The javascript:

```
angular.module('listAndDetails', [])

  .value('users', [
    { name:'Damien', email:'damien@domain.com', desc:'Damien details go here...', country:'US', address:'address1'},
    { name:'Alex', email:'alex@domain.com', desc:'Alex details go here...', country:'UK', address:'address2'}
  ])

  .controller('ListAndOneDetailCtrl', function ($scope, users) {
    $scope.users = users;

    $scope.selectUser = function (user) {
      $scope.selectedUser = user;
    };

    $scope.isSelected = function (user) {
      return $scope.selectedUser === user;
    };
  })

  .controller('ListAndManyDetailsCtrl', function ($scope, users) {
    $scope.users = users;
  })

  .controller('UserCtrl', function ($scope) {

    $scope.toggleSelected = function () {
      $scope.selected = !$scope.selected;
    };

    $scope.isSelected = function (user) {
      return $scope.selected;
    };
  });
```

The div on top attempts to show a nested table upon clicking the list item, but nothing happens.

The div at the bottom attempts to show child td items upon clicking the list item and it works exactly as expected.

Does anyone have any idea what the problem is when I'm trying to expand to show a nested table using ng-switch? And how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You have a two errors in your code.

**First**

In controller `ListAndOneDetailCtrl` on `ng-click` you don't have a function `toggleSelected`.

**Second**

In first table with controller `ListAndOneDetailCtrl` you don't have tag `td` in nested table.

See correct code in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/b5qdah7t/4/)

```js
angular.module('listAndDetails', [])

  .value('users', [
    { name:'Damien', email:'damien@domain.com', desc:'Damien details go here...', country:'US', address:'address1'},
    { name:'Alex', email:'alex@domain.com', desc:'Alex details go here...', country:'UK', address:'address2'}
  ])

  .controller('ListAndOneDetailCtrl', function ($scope, users) {
    $scope.users = users;

    $scope.selectUser = function (user) {
      $scope.selectedUser = user;
    };

    $scope.isSelected = function (user) {
      return $scope.selectedUser === user;
    };
  })

  .controller('ListAndManyDetailsCtrl', function ($scope, users) {
    $scope.users = users;
  })

  .controller('UserCtrl', function ($scope) {

    $scope.toggleSelected = function () {
      $scope.selected = !$scope.selected;
    };

    $scope.isSelected = function (user) {
      return $scope.selected;
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="listAndDetails">
<div>
    <table class="table table-bordered" ng-controller="ListAndOneDetailCtrl">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>e-mail</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody ng-repeat="user in users" ng-click="selectUser(user)" ng-switch on="isSelected(user)">
        <tr>
            <td>{{user.name}}</td>
            <td>{{user.email}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-switch-when="true" class="light-gray">
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Country</td>
                    <td>Address</td>
                    <td>Description</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>{{user.country}}</td>
                    <td>{{user.address}}</td>
                    <td>{{user.desc}}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<div ng-controller="ListAndManyDetailsCtrl">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>e-mail</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody ng-repeat="user in users" ng-controller="UserCtrl" ng-click="toggleSelected()" ng-switch on="isSelected()">
        <tr>
            <td>{{user.name}}</td>
            <td>{{user.email}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-switch-when="true" class="light-gray">
            <td>{{user.country}}</td>
            <td>{{user.address}}</td>
            <td>{{user.desc}}</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

There were two problems:

- you needed a td section enclosing your table;

```html
<tr>
  <td>
    <table>
      <!-- table information -->
    </table>
  </td>
</tr>
```

- the controller needed some modifications so that the selected user could have a value.

```html
  .controller('ListAndOneDetailCtrl', function ($scope, users) {
    $scope.users = users;
    
    $scope.toggleSelected = function(user) {
      $scope.selectedUser = user;
    };

    $scope.selectUser = function (user) {
      $scope.selectedUser = user;
    };

    $scope.isSelected = function (user) {
      return $scope.selectedUser === user;
    };
  })
```

Here's an updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jp43agsb/2/